# Iis7 URL rewrite for whole directory, stripping index.aspx

Tags: .net, iis-7, url-rewriting

Iis7 windows 2008 server
Iis rewrite modual
.net 4

Very simple question, I am using the rewrite modual and find it pretty good, but I need help setting up a rule I just can't seem to get right.

http://www.vinylsearcher.com/dance-music/downtempo-records/

Criteria:
Any request to the dance-music folder must strip index.aspx off the end so it ends like:

http://www.vinylsearcher.com/dance-music/downtempo-records/

Not

http://www.vinylsearcher.com/dance-music/downtempo-records/index.aspx

But also must work for :

http://www.vinylsearcher.com/dance-music/downtempo-records/mostexpensive/index.aspx

Needs to rewrite to:

http://www.vinylsearcher.com/dance-music/downtempo-records/mostexpensive/

I have gone round and round in circles so would appreciate some help.

Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

add this to the web.config file underneath the /defaultDocument section:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/(media|skin|js)/" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="index.aspx" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```